# how to add new div before another?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a new div before another div in the body tag. How can I do that?

The html

```
<body class="variant-classic magazine notouch">
   <div id="head" class="hfeed" tabindex="0">
   <div id="header-container">
   // other div areas
</body>
```

the script I wrote

```
var container = document.getElementById('header-container');
var conn = document.createElement('div');

conn.style.position='absolute';
conn.style.float='left';
conn.style.width='100%';
conn.style.height='50px';
conn.style.background='gray';

container.insertBefore(conn, container);
```

The Error

```
 Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The       
 node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
```

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ sorry type mistake.

Comment: An element can't be its own child. The second argument is the reference element before which you want to add new element(s), it must be a child of the element having the called `insertBefore` method. In your case you probably want `document.body.insertBefore(conn, container);`

Comment: @Teemu So, how to add new div befor another?

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="parentElement">
  <span id="childElement">foo bar</span>
</div>

<script>
// Create a new, plain <span> element
var sp1 = document.createElement("span");

// Get a reference to the element, before we want to insert the element
var sp2 = document.getElementById("childElement");
// Get a reference to the parent element
var parentDiv = sp2.parentNode;

// Insert the new element into the DOM before sp2
parentDiv.insertBefore(sp1, sp2);
</script>
```

Comment: Does above meaningful to understand the insertBefore()?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please close all your **`div`**.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/ghjpkj69/2/).

The function `.insertBefore()` is to be applied on parent element.

Here is the snippet.

```js
var parent = document.body;
var container = document.getElementById('header-container');
var conn = document.createElement('div');

conn.style.position = 'absolute';
conn.style.float = 'left';
conn.style.width = '100%';
conn.style.height = '50px';
conn.style.background = 'gray';

parent.insertBefore(conn, container);
```

```html
<body class="variant-classic magazine notouch">
  <div id="head" class="hfeed" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div id="header-container"></div>
  // other div areas
</body>
```

The text `// other div areas` is not visible after the insertion of new `div` because you have set `position=absolute`, and hence, the text is hidden behind the `div`.

Comment: At Google blogger code, body doesn't have a id. How to fix this?

Comment: Its gets even more easier then. `var parent = document.body;`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **inserts a set of Node objects or DOMString objects before the first child of the Parent Node** you may consider using:

```
parentElement.prepend(newFirstChild);
```

In your case it will be:

```
    var container = document.getElementById('header-container');
    var conn = document.createElement('div');

    conn.style.position = 'absolute';
    conn.style.float = 'left';
    conn.style.width = '100%';
    conn.style.height = '50px';
    conn.style.background = 'gray';

    container.prepend(conn);
```

This is a new addition in ES7. It is currently available in Chrome, FireFox, and Opera.

Transpilers should be able to handle it until it becomes available everywhere.

more info: [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend)

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

```
var txt3 = document.createElement("div");  

txt3.style.position='absolute';
txt3.style.float='left';
txt3.style.width='100%';
txt3.style.height='50px';
txt3.style.background='gray';

 $( "#head" ).wrap( txt3 );
```